# Change button_label on Shopify when hover

Tags: jquery, css, shopify, liquid

I have this liquid code:

```
<a href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}" class="btn--full">
                <div class="flex-btn">
                    {{ block.settings.button_label }}
                    {% render  'icon-arrow-right' %}
                </div>
            </a>
```

And I need to change the **button_label** when I hover.
Is there any way to do it with only CSS? Or should I use data- attributes and jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you.

You need to add a data attribute containing the wanted 'hover text', as you suggested yourself. Heres how I did it:

```
<a href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}" class="btn--full" >
  <div class="flex-btn">
    <span data-hover_text="Second placeholder text">
      {{ block.settings.button_label }}
    </span>
    {% render  'icon-arrow-right' %}
  </div>
</a>
```

Notice that I put the text into a `span`. This is important because we don't want to interfere with the `icon-arrow-right`.

Next up we need the jQuery. Here how I implemented it:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('.btn--full').on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
        flipText($('.flex-btn span'));
    });
});

function flipText(el) {
    // Get and store the current text present in element
    var currentText = $(el).text();
    
    // Get and store the placeholder text from the 'hover_text' data-attribute
    var placeholderText = $(el).data('hover_text');

    // Replace the current text with the placeholder text
    $(el).text(placeholderText);

    // Replace the data attribute 'hover_text' with the current text
    $(el).data('hover_text', currentText);
}
```

Hopefully that helps. I can elaborate on anything if you need it, so let me know if you do.

Comment: It's a simple CSS solution. Using JS here is unnecessary and jQuery is overkill :)

Comment: Right, I would also prefer your solution :p

Comment: I know jQuery is overkill, but Shopify still use it  :)

Comment: Well its not overkill in general. It has many great use cases. However for this I would recommend, that you try out @HymnZzy's solution first. If you want to use jQuery, then you're free to use my solution :p

Comment: Both solutions works well! The problem is: I need change text when the user hover the `.btn--full` class, not the `.flex btn span` class. Is there anyway that I can target the parent class with jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: @AnaSpinola in this specific case, keeping Shopify and e-commerce point of view, it's always good to use browsers inbuilt system to get things done and use JavaScript / jQuery only if there is no other option.

Comment: @AnaSpinola, I have changed the code in my answer to trigger on the parent class. This should accomplish what you want. However, I would still advice you to try and make use of HymnZzy's solution. :)

Comment: @ralphwayTOW the HymnZzy's solution had the same problem. Now it's working!

Comment: @AnaSpinola All right, that's great news. You could give me the 'correct answer' if you don't mind. That would help me out loads, as well as 'close down' the question :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires no jQuery / Javascript. Try this.

```
<a href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}" class="btn--full">
  <div class="flex-btn hoverTextArea">
    <span class="normalText">{{ block.settings.button_label }}</span>
    <span class="hoverText">TEXT TO BE DISPLAYED ON HOVER</span>
    {% render  'icon-arrow-right' %}
  </div>
</a>
<style>
  .hoverTextArea:hover .normalText,.hoverText{ display:none }
  .hoverTextArea:hover .hoverText{ display:initial }
</style>
```